# Oracle SQL print first and last entry in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe-18.4

So I need to print the oldest and youngest result in a table my code is

```
SELECT client.clientfirstname, client.clientlastname, client.clientdob
FROM client
order by (client.clientdob) DESC
FETCH first 1 row only


SELECT client.clientfirstname, client.clientlastname, client.clientdob
FROM client
order by (client.clientdob) ASC
FETCH first 1 ROW ONLY;
```

these 2 by themselves will return the right value but I cant get them both to run at once, it seems I cant use a Union with this setup, if possible a single select statement where I can get both the first and last would be even better. I am also using SQL developer if there is way to get both of these to show in the same SQL query result window that would be fine.

Comment: Did you tried UNION ALL solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT client.clientfirstname, client.clientlastname, client.clientdob
FROM client where 
client.clientdob=(select max(client.clientdob) from client)
or 
client.clientdob=(select min(client.clientdob) from client)
```

Comment: sql dev gives me a "SQL command not properly ended" error when I try that. same with union.

Comment: @Comradedrago, I've updated the answer - you can take a look

Comment: This works mostly only issue is that multiple people share a DOB value for MAX and MIN so that's why I needed to limit it to 1 max and 1 min. Is that possible with the min and max options?

Comment: @Comradedrago, you can try Soumendra Mishra's solution if that works for your case

Comment: yours worked great I just added a Fetch first 2 row only and that fixed the issue, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Comradedrago, great to hear that it helped u :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` like this below:

```
select c1.* from (select client.clientfirstname, client.clientlastname, client.clientdob, row_number() over (order by client.clientdob ASC) as rn FROM client) c1 where c1.rn =1
union all
select c2.* from (select client.clientfirstname, client.clientlastname, client.clientdob, row_number() over (order by client.clientdob DESC) as rn FROM client) c2 where c2.rn =1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use analyitical function `row_number()` to get the desired result,

```
select *
  from
(
select cl.clientfirstname
     , cl.clientlastname
     , cl.clientdob 
     , row_number() over (order by cl.clientdob desc) max_rn
     , row_number() over (order by cl.clientdob asc) min_rn
FROM client cl
) t
where (max_rn = 1 or min_rn = 1)
```